# MVC Search Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello guys i hope you all are doing great, so i am working on a project with my buddy but we both are intermediate programmers and stuck into a place so i need your help...

the problem is I'm stuck in a certain code which is for "search the dish":

[ShowAll list page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UUga.jpg)

[After selecting value from a combo box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25atE.jpg)

it's doing post back from java script method as you can see in the picture but i think my code is incomplete because i can't get value from database i is showing the list on my "ShowAll page" but when i choose a value from combo box it doesn't show anything..

**ActionResult Code**

```
public ActionResult ShowAll()
    {

        var a = from tb in me.RecipeTables select tb;

        return View(a.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowAll(string searchDish)
    {
        var k = me.RecipeTables.Where(l => l.recipeName == searchDish);
        return View(k);
    }
```

**View Code wit java script function**

```
<html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectedIndexChanged()
    {
        this.myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("ShowAll", "RecipeView", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", name = "myForm", enctype="multipart/form-data"}))  
 %>
<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    <select id="searchDish" name="searchDish" onchange="SelectedIndexChanged()">
        <option value="0">Select any</option>
        <option value="1">biryani</option>
        <option value="2">fried rice</option>
        <option value="3">Nihari</option>
        <option value="4">Tikka</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

need help!!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality you need to add Ajax call on OnChange of searchDish
but you need to add  in your code for return result
Note : for this functionality you need to add **JQuery libraries** in your code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

**Ajax Call :**

```js
 $('#searchDish').change(function () {
 var vid = $("#searchDish").val();
     $.ajax({
                            url: "/RecipeView/ShowAll?id=" + vid,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "html",
                            data: 'json',
                            async: false,
                            success: function (data) {

                                $('#divLanguage').html(data);

                            }
                        });
       });
```

Cheers !!

Comment: nope it didn't work take a look at my code and then view page where i made this list

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the  i was sending string value in constructor and retrieving in numbers so i just changed it to  and you can even do this that don't give any value it will work.. :)